# How to find PCR PID in m2ts file?

Tags: video-streaming, low-level, mpeg, mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

**I need to know PCR PID in my m2ts file.**
I think I need to perform the following steps:

1. Find TS packet with PID 0. This is a PAT.
2. Parse the PAT to get the PID of the PMT.
3. Parse the PMT to get the PID of the PCR.

But I have some trouble with first and second steps. Please see following TS packet:

```
47 40 00 13 00 00 B0 0D 00 01 C1 00 00 00 01 F0 00 2A B1 04 B2 FF FF FF FF ...
```

"47 40 00 13" is "0100 0111 0100 0000 0000 0000 0001 0011" in binary.

PID is 0x0000, Payload Unit Start Indicator flag is 1 and Contains payload flag is 1.

According to TS reader I know that PMT PID for this file is 0x1000.

But this packet hasn't included a pair of bytes 10 00.

**Have I chosen the right TS packet with PAT ?
Please explain from which byte the PAT starts.**

Comment: Rohit Thanks! It's better now!

Comment: aergistal thanks a lot!